# lightbox showing in post back

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, button, lightbox

We are using asp.net button to open light box.But because of post back light box doent appear.
We tried to use html button, it opens the light box but the validations in page is not controlled.How we may manage this?

```
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.Append("<script type='text/javascript\'>");
            sb.Append("$(function () {");
            sb.Append("$('#dialog').dialog({");
            sb.Append("bgiframe: true, autoOpen: false, height: 500,");
            sb.Append("minWidth: 780, resizable: false, modal: true, position:'center',");
            sb.Append("open: function (type, data) {");
            sb.Append("$(this).parent().appendTo('form');");
            sb.Append("}");
            sb.Append("});");
            sb.Append("$('#dialog_link').click(function () {");
            sb.Append("$('#dialog').dialog('open');");
            sb.Append("return false;");
            sb.Append("});");
            sb.Append("});");
            sb.Append("</script>");

            ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "Lightbox", sb.ToString(), false);
```

Not working on ButtonClick event are there any mistakes in code ?

Answer (score 0):

How about this

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page 
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        buttonId.Attributes.Add("onClick", "return false;");
    }
}
```

This should stop the postback from firing but still give you what you need.